# Custom TabView with Intent in Android

Tags: android, customization, tabview

I want to create Tabview like below in Image. I tried it but can't get proper view.

[image: Custom Tab]

Here is My Code.. It's not give exact view that I want. So, How can I customized it.

```
public class BandInfo extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

TabHost tabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.band_info);

    tabHost = getTabHost();

    tabHost.getTabWidget().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerbar);


    // Tab for Bio
    TabSpec bioSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Bio");
    // Setting Title for Tab
    bioSpec.setIndicator("Bio");
    Intent bioIntent = new Intent(this,Bio.class);
    bioSpec.setContent(bioIntent);

    // Tab for Upcoing Shows
    TabSpec upcomingShowSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Upcoming Shows");
    upcomingShowSpec.setIndicator("Upcoming Shows");
    Intent upcomingShowIntent = new Intent(this, UpcomingShow.class);
    upcomingShowSpec.setContent(upcomingShowIntent);

    // Tab for Band Members
    TabSpec bandMemberSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Band Members");
    bandMemberSpec.setIndicator("Band Members");
    Intent bandMemberIntent = new Intent(this, BandMembers.class);
    bandMemberSpec.setContent(bandMemberIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(bioSpec); // Adding Bio Tab
    tabHost.addTab(upcomingShowSpec); // Adding Upcoming Show Tab
    tabHost.addTab(bandMemberSpec); // Adding Band Members Tab

    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerbar);
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.footer_saprater);
}
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.footerbar);
    }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bandmember_active);
}
```

Please Help me with some code...
Thanks in Advance..

[image: Output Screen]

This is an output Screen I get.

Comment: have you done anything?

Comment: yes I try it, but Title name of tab is not set in center..

Comment: Hi... You're still not able to solve the problem ??

Comment: Use TextView with background image instead of using TabView.

Comment: Please show the image that you are getting with this code. So that others can understand what is the result you are getting with this code and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Check My Code and output Screen @shree202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyy i found this. Try this. you'll surely make it.

http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/

For setting width,

`tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width =(int) 30;`

Also check this link: http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-custom-tab-layouts-just-using.html and http://www.speakingcode.com/2011/12/01/creating-custom-views-for-tabs-in-an-android-activity-using-tabhost-and-tabwidget/